# Mongoid field type: Moped::BSON::ObjectId with rabl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, rabl

Scenario: Rails + Mongoid + Rabl

I have a classes like

```
class User
   has_many :cards
   field    :name
```

and

```
class Card
   belongs_to :user
   field      :anotheruser, type:Moped::BSON::ObjectId
```

I'm rabl newbie so my question for you rabl experts out there is that is there an elegant way to query "anotheruser" object via BSON:ObjectId straight from rabl. I can do the magic in my controller for sure, but it would be very handy feature if available.

Thanks.

P

Answer (score 0):

Your classes look wrong, should look like

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many :cards
  field    :name

class Card
   include Mongoid::Document
   has_and_belongs_to_many :user
```

You should be able to use the normal relationships `user.cards` and `cards.users`

Comment: Thanks. 

I did (over) simplify my question and left Mongoid includes out of example.

I can use relation cards <-> user, no problem. The issue is that I have another field with BSON:ObjectId that holds a id of another user object. So there's no actual relation specified.

Comment: I understand that this may be considered as a "design flaw", but since Mongoid is not at its best with many-to-many relations I thought that this might be an alternative route.

Comment: Furthermore, the questions is how to make this kind of query from rabl.